# the use of both to show emphasis and experimentalist and theoretician communities

Tags: word-usage, word-order

In your opinion is *both* superfluous in the following sentence?

> Efforts from both experimentalist and theoretician communities, started to increase over the last decades in order to turn the hydrogen energy from a possible solution to a reality.

I used *both*, even if it seems superfluous, to show emphasis that, although at the beginning  of hydrogen energy research, most of researches were experimentalists, it turns out in the last decades that theoreticians are interested in such fields as well.

A second doubt I have is if the expression "experimentalist and theoretician communities" is correct in the way I'm  using it. I've read many times expressions like: "Each session, devoted to a kind of spectroscopy, will include invited contributions from both experimentalists and theoreticians" or "time-scale motions remains a challenge to experimentalists and theoreticians alike". But in my sentence I'd like to make clear that  theoreticians and experimentalist working in different fields, as for example catalysis, electrochemistry and computational chemistry, are now given attention to hydrogen energy.  That's why I used *communities*.

In you opinion, does it make sense?

Comment: Why would you put a comma after *both*?

Comment: @JLG: Why would you bother to ask someone who appears not to know how to properly punctuate a sentence why he's done it incorrectly? Ignorance is as good a reason as "Typo!" in this case. Whatever the reason, it won't help you or anyone else answer the OP's question, will it?

Comment: "The efforts of experimentalists as well as theoreticians" could be better, though that's not the only alternative.

Comment: Commenters better note the user's rep/ profile before offering advice or down/ close voting.

Comment: @Kris: I always check before offering answers. OP has no profile and rep of 2. Downvotes prevent adding comments, giving answers, etc. Yesterday or the day before I registered for another SE area and was lucky to get 100 rep points free because I associated my new account with this one. At first, though, I couldn't do anything but read because I started out with 1 rep point only.

Answer (score 1):

No, the expression is incorrect for a few reasons.

> First, as JLG obliquely points out, the comma after *both* is incorrect.
>   Second, the word *both* is superfluous in this case.
>   Third, the names of the two communities seem a little abnormal to me.

Try this: *Effort(s) from theoreticians and experimenters...*

However, a felicitous phrase requires a context. This expression has no context; therefore, it's pointless to ask whether it's correct. Even granting that my revision is grammatically and semantically correct, whether it's semantically and stylistically optimal is not determinable because there is no context that permits judgment.

Provide a full sentence or perhaps even a larger context. Tell us the field of study. The more we know about what you want to say and why, the easier it will be to help you craft a reasonable expression or at least answer a reasonable question about it's grammaticality and style and usage: in context.

Comment: The generally accepted word in the physical sciences is "experimentalist" and not "experimenter".

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for that information. In the biomed world we call them "basic scientists" (PhDs in whatever biomed field) because they do basic science (experimental) articles; practicing MDs do clinical articles. The theoreticians ought to be called "theoreticalists" at the very least, then, just for rhetorical balance & structural parallelism. MW3UDE: "2: one who likes to experiment as an innovator, artist, or explorer [_a bold **experimentalist** with paragraph and punctuation_ —H.G.Wells]": almost sounds like a characterization of Joyce's _Finnegans Wake_, but Wells wasn't +ly impressed.

Comment: @BillFranke Thank you very much for your help.
The complete sentence would be the following:
"Efforts, from both experimentalist and theoretician communities, started to increase over the last decades in order to turn the hydrogen energy from a possible solution to a reality" The field is physicochemistry

Comment: @ziulfer: Thank you for the sentence & info. I think I might revise it just slightly: "_Efforts from (both) the experimentalist and the theoretician communities began {to increase / increasing [CHOOSE ONE]} over the past **n# [How many?]** decades to {turn the potential solution of hydrogen energy into / make the potential solution of hydrogen energy [CHOOSE ONE]} a reality._"

Comment: The _felicitous phrase_, no doubt employing words containing the ubiquitous schwa, seems to have met its end at the beak of the frumious Bandersnatch (either that or  MετάEd, FumbleFingers, Will Hunting, & RegDwighт). But I'll resurrect Bill's expression.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I often sacrifice felicity for clarity and to allow the authors to make their own style choices, especially if I've rewritten a great deal of the paper, which is sometimes the case. And when I'm not all that familiar with the style of the field, I scan a few articles in the target journal for my reference. But authors often want to copy structures they've seen in top-ranked journals by well-known authors. I'm sure that my revision can be improved, and I welcome any suggestions from anyone. I am, after all, still only an ENL (English as a native language) student.

Comment: I suggest you never try a rewrite of "Jabberwocky".

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: No point in trying to make perfection better than it is. But there's no need for you to rewrite "The Hunting of the Snark", either, is there?